# How to tell if there is a 1 in every row of a matrix such that each 1 is in a different column?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Given an `n X n` matrix containing `1`s or `0`s, I need to pick some `1`s from the matrix such that:

- There is a `1` in every row.
- Every `1` that I pick is in a different column.

How do I **check** if it is possible to do that?

The approach I could think of has exponential complexity : It's much like the `N Queens` problem. Pick a `1` in the 1st row, recurse into the 2nd row and so on. If it isn't possible at any stage, backtrack.

But is there a better way?

Comment: Are you trying to generate such `1`s, or determine whether a given matrix has this property?

Comment: @Adam, I'm trying to check if a matrix has this property.

Comment: This is perfect matching problem for bipartite graph - check if there is matching in graph where left vertexes are columns, right vertexes are rows and edges are ones in the matrix. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Matching

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to determine if a matrix is in reduced row echelon form.

Comment: I don't think this works as a matrix full of 1s obviously has a 1 in every row and you can pick n 1s that are all in different columns

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a dynamic programming problem to me.

Everytime you recurse you delete an entire row + column from the matrix.  At the bottom of your recursion you'll have [1] and [0].  The [1] matrix is "successful" the [0] matrix is "unsuccessful".  The next stage up you'll have 2^4 matrices from [0 0; 0 0] to [1 1; 1 1].  Some of these will be successful, some will not be successful.

It seems like sorting the rows of the matrix so that rows with lots of 1s are processed last will help